# Partial Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

This is actually a very easy problem but I am brand new to this subject and I just don't the mechanism on how to do it yet. The question is:

Determine the solution of $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=(\sin x)\rho$ which satisfies $\rho (x,0)=\cos x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, forget the fact that $\rho$ is a function of two variables and just look at it as a function of $t$. If I tell you that $\sin x$ is a constant $A$ and $\cos x$ just some constant $B$, how would you solve the ODE $$\frac{d\rho}{dt}=A\rho\\\rho(0) = B,$$

where $\rho$ is just a function of time?

Once you do that, plug $A$ and $B$ for what they are and you will have $\rho(x,t).$

Comment: well you would have $c_1e^{At}$ which is just $cos(x)e^{sin(x)t}$. Would that be right?

Comment: Indeed it would. You can verify your solution by calculating $$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}$$ and checking that it equals $\sin x \rho(x,t)$. You can also see that $\rho(x,0) = \cos x$